# Запрет закрытия формы и помещение приложения в автозагрузку

Tags: c#

1. Скажите, как можно сделать так, чтобы программа при первом запуске копировалась в папку автозагрузки?
2. Как сделать, чтобы форму нельзя было закрыть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В инсталляторе программы пропишите копирование ярлыка в папку автозагрузки, или создайте соответствующий ключ в реестре.
2. Как я понимаю, нельзя форму закрыть до выполнения какого - либо действия (не использовать же все-время диспетчер задач)? Поэтому в обработчике события формы `Closing` организовать проверку и запрещать (разрешать) закрытие при помощи `e.Close = false` или `e.Close = true`

Comment: Но вот ещё вопрос, а как сделать так что бы файлы копировались, не после УСТАНОВКИ, а после запуска? И какой для этого код?

Comment: В функции static void Main() пропиши соответствующий код. Наизусть не помню, но ты свободно можешь найти ВСЮ информацию. Смотри работа с файлами и реестром в C# (твоя версия). Если не будет родных функций для создания ярлыка - используй WinAPI. Тут разобраться легко, а главное - полезно. Удачи!

Comment: Небольшая поправка: не e.Close, а e.Cancel

Comment: Ошибся. e.Cancel = true отмена закрытия.

Answer (score 2):

Добавь этот код в свой проект:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

if (registryKey.GetValue("MyAppName") == null)
    registryKey.SetValue("MyAppName", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

И будет тебе автозагрузка при старте. Про Form.Closing [[@Вячеслав](/users/4185/%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE)](/users/4185/%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE) уже написал.